# How to create a Jlabel inside JTextArea like in Facebook?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, jtextfield

Is there a way I can create a JTextArea or JTextField with some JLabels inside it, like in this screenshot from Facebook:

[image: sample]

What I am trying to do is put some JButtons with titles like "Apple", "Orange", ... When user clicks on a JButton of those, say "Orange", a Jlabel with the word Orange will be added to the JTextArea or JTextField. If user clicked on the [x] on the Jlabel, the word will be removed from the field.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would solve this in a different way: create a `JPanel` with the border you see. Add a `JTextField` without any borders into it, and simply insert your `JLabel`s to the left (e.g. using `BorderLayout` in combination with `FlowLayout`). With a little tweaking of borders and spacings you should be able to create a very similar appearance without having to create new components.

Comment: Very nice suggestion ... I have started implementing this. I am stuck at making the [x] icon and its event, but initially it is working fine.

Comment: That can also be implemented by a `JPanel`, two `JLabel`s, and a `BorderLayout`. :)